# rxjs obervable.interval(); throws not a function exception in browser

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs5, angular-observable

The component.ts file is given below. Why it is throwing an error even after importing interval from rxjs/add/observable/interval.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
      const myNumber = Observable.interval(1000);
      myNumber.subscribe(
        (number: number) => {
          console.log(number);
        }
      );
  }
}
```

**Error Messages in the browser:**

> ERROR TypeError:
>   rxjs_Observable__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Observable.interval is
>   not a function
>       at HomeComponent.push../src/app/home/home.component.ts.HomeComponent.ngOnInit
>   (home.component.ts:15)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:20665)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:21929)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:21891)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:22525)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:22485)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (HomeComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.js:22477)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:21873)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:22114) View_HomeComponent_Host_0 @ HomeComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 proxyClass @ compiler.js:17945
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError
>   @ core.js:22729
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError
>   @ core.js:14645 (anonymous) @ core.js:16895
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @
>   zone.js:388 push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @
>   zone.js:138
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular
>   @ core.js:16115
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @
>   core.js:16895 (anonymous) @ core.js:16779
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @
>   zone.js:388 onInvoke @ core.js:16156
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @
>   zone.js:387 push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @
>   zone.js:138 push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run
>   @ core.js:16070 next @ core.js:16779 schedulerFn @ core.js:12609
>   push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.**tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
>   push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next
>   @ Subscriber.js:134
>   push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next
>   @ Subscriber.js:77
>   push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   @ Subscriber.js:54
>   push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @
>   Subject.js:47
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @
>   core.js:12593 checkStable @ core.js:16125 onHasTask @ core.js:16169
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @
>   zone.js:441
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount
>   @ zone.js:461
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @
>   zone.js:285 push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @
>   zone.js:205 drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595 Promise.then (async)
>   scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @
>   zone.js:410 push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask
>   @ zone.js:232
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @
>   zone.js:252 scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
>   ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:962
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule
>   @ core.js:16660 ./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
>   __webpack_require** @ bootstrap:78 0 @ main.ts:12
>   **webpack_require** @ bootstrap:78 checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45 webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32 (anonymous) @ main.js:1
>   HomeComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR CONTEXT
>   DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 0, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…},
>   elView: {…}} View_HomeComponent_Host_0 @
>   HomeComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 proxyClass @ compiler.js:17945
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.DebugContext_.logError
>   @ core.js:22729
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError
>   @ core.js:14650 (anonymous) @ core.js:16895
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @
>   zone.js:388 push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @
>   zone.js:138
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular
>   @ core.js:16115
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @
>   core.js:16895 (anonymous) @ core.js:16779
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @
>   zone.js:388 onInvoke @ core.js:16156
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @
>   zone.js:387 push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @
>   zone.js:138 push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run
>   @ core.js:16070 next @ core.js:16779 schedulerFn @ core.js:12609
>   push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.**tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
>   push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next
>   @ Subscriber.js:134
>   push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next
>   @ Subscriber.js:77
>   push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   @ Subscriber.js:54
>   push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @
>   Subject.js:47
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @
>   core.js:12593 checkStable @ core.js:16125 onHasTask @ core.js:16169
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @
>   zone.js:441
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount
>   @ zone.js:461
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @
>   zone.js:285 push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @
>   zone.js:205 drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595 Promise.then (async)
>   scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @
>   zone.js:410 push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask
>   @ zone.js:232
>   push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @
>   zone.js:252 scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
>   ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:962
>   push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule
>   @ core.js:16660 ./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
>   __webpack_require** @ bootstrap:78 0 @ main.ts:12
>   **webpack_require** @ bootstrap:78 checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45 webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32 (anonymous) @ main.js:1

Comment: You can find an example for RxJS v6+ here : https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html

Comment: works here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgvark?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: What RxJS version you have?

Comment: version 6.3.3 @martin

Comment: Sice RxJS 5.5 you should use just `import { interval } from 'rxjs';`

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
      const myNumber = interval(1000);
      myNumber.subscribe(
        (number: number) => {
          console.log(number);
        }
      );
  }
}
```